# Determine the volume of $A:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 : \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq f(z)\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $f\geq0$. Determine $A:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3 : \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq f(z)\}$.

"Normal" substitution $(x=rcos(\phi),y=rsin(\phi))$ did not help a lot, since I dont have any information about f(z)

Comment: If you intersect $A$ with a plane $z=z_0$ you get the set of all points $(x,y,z_0)$ with $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq f(z_0)$.  Does that help?

Comment: Hint (perhaps): The answer will be given in terms of an integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\dots) dz$ involving $f(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track. Using polar coordinates, we find that the volume of $A$ is $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^{f(z)} r\, dr\, dz\, d\theta = \pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)^2\, dz.$$